# Spring Boot Xss Not Working for request headers

Tags: spring-boot, xss

XSS-FIlter Not working for request headers .It is working for request parameters only. public String getHeader(String name) method call back does not work for request headers.I have used following project from git. 
https://github.com/mehditahmasebi/spring/tree/master/spring-xss-filter.

I have just import the project ,start it and using postman trying to add pramas and header with xss string .It is working fine for parameters but header is not being called.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10228396/m-soleimani .Could you please help

```
@Override
public String getHeader(String name) {
    String value = super.getHeader(name);
    return stripXSS(value);
}
```

This method is not called for request header when rest api is called using postman. Porstman url 
http://localhost:8086/personService/test?name=rahul<> with header mykey2=<> .SO rahul<> will encoded(sanitize) but requestheader does not.So While debugging the code I see that getHeader(String name) method is not being called for header 'mykey2'.Though header is reaching to controller and I am getting value as <> so request header is not getting sanitize.

Comment: what is exactly the problem ? Does your application not add the header ? or does it not block some XSS ?

Comment: The exact problem is that  I am not able to rectifie the request header that contains xss tag.On other hand request param is working fine .If I add HTML tags in request params it is getting ecoded but request header is not able to encode .Please let me know if I need to explain more

Comment: @SPoint Did you got my question or need more information on it.

Comment: OK. As you did not share the code used, I can't help you much as I want. getHeader is only called if you manipulate header, you must call it direclty if you want it to be sanitize. It is not a mandatory filter that is sanitizing the header.